# Unable to deploy my react app to google cloud platform vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I started learning Google Cloud Platform recently. So, created a trial account. Can I deploy my learning web application to the VM I created and browse it from my local? I tried running `gcloud app deploy` from my vm but getting error...

```
== ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission==
```

Comment: The `gcloud app deploy` command deploys your app to App Engine and not to your VM. Start reading the documentation and then figure out which service your want to use. Google has good getting started examples.

Answer (score 1):

VM (Compute Engine) and App engine are two different things, you can read more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697189/4539626). `gcloud app deploy` is app engine utility and used to deploy your application to app engine.

If you have your code in compute engine and want to deploy to app engine, make sure service account associated with your vm has necessary scopes and permissions. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909420/4539626).

On addition to that you can start with [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/deploying-an-app-engine-app) for deploying your web application.